# My contact formular has worked before - now it doesn't - php

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I have a problem with my php-contactformular. 
It has worked all the time i've used it (for more years) but now it doesn't work anymore.

It doesn't say any error message - but just says "The email was sent" (in Danish) when i push the button, and all the fields is filled. 
But i don't recieve any email.

This is the code:

```html
<form method="post" action="kontakt.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <label>Navn:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit navn her.." name="navn"/>
    
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv din email her.." name="email"/>
    
     <label>Telefonnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Skriv dit telefonnummer her.." name="telefon"/>

    <label >Besked:</label>
    <textarea placeholder="Skriv din besked her.." cols="20" rows="5" id="kommentarbox" name="besked"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="button">Send mail</button>
  </form>
        
        
        <?php 
     $til = 'xxxx@hotmail.com';
     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
     $navn = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'navn');
  $telefon = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefon');
 $besked = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'besked');

   if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['navn'])) 
{
  
    if (empty($_POST['email']))  
    {
        echo "<p class='fejl'>";
    }
    elseif (empty($_POST['navn'])) 
    {
        echo "<p class='fejl'>Input name</p>"; 
    }
 
    else 
    { 
  
        $telefon = "Mail fra " . $_POST['navn'];
  
        $tekst = "Mail fra: " . $_POST['navn'] . 
  "\n \n telefon: " . $_POST['telefon'] .  
  "\n \n besked: " . $_POST['besked'] . 
   "\n \n \n \n Kontaktoplysninger: \n \n Mail: " . $_POST['email'] . 
  
        $email =  $_POST['email'];

         mail($til, $telefon, $tekst, $email); 
        echo "<p id='sendt'> Emailen er nu sendt!</p>"; 
    }
}
```

I have tried to search, but i can't find anything that is the exactly same problem :(

Is there anyone who knows what is wrong with it?

Thanks!

Comment: if (empty($_POST['email']))  
    {
        echo "<p class='fejl'>Du skal indtaste din email</p>"; 
    }
    elseif (empty($_POST['navn']))
    {
        echo "<p class='fejl'>Du skal indtaste dit navn</p>"; 
    }
 
    else 
    {

Comment: Sorry - I have deleted too much. There is Comments between, and i didn't wanted them to come in this post. This is what it says

Comment: No worries, it would still been closed with other.